# Website where I could find words

Tags: phonetics

Do you know any website where I could search a word by a sound from it's IPA transcription ( for instance like ə and get awesome, jonathan etc.). Thank you

Comment: Try http://www.benbriedis.com/phonetic/search.php More resources are mentioned in the answers to [How does one find a word with a rhyming middle syllable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113651/how-does-one-find-a-word-with-a-rhyming-middle-syllable)